# Displaying a specific post category in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display posts from a specific category on my website which currently displays all posts. Here is the code I have on the section of the page below:

---

```
    <?php

    // the query

    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>18)); ?>

    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->

    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- end of the loop -->



    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code inside the loop to something like below code and here `cat = 3` determines the category 3.

```
<ul>
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<li>
<h3>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
</h3>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the argument `cat = 3` or category id for which you want to show post